# How should i zoom to full screen in Cocos2d-x2.0 for Android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

In the Cocos2d-x2.0:
i opened view->setDesignResolutionSize(480, 320);
but some of devices has two black sides.it's not very nice.

how should i zoom to full screen in Cocos2d-x2.0 for Android?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the black sides appearing is cocos2d-x try to keep the height-width ratio since there are too man different ratios on android devices. To avoid image distortion, they force implement the same ratio as your ResolutionSize.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to handle multi-screen resolution support for your app. You can find [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Multi_resolution_support). What you are experiencing is called letter boxing.